# Eigenvalues of diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Problem:

> Let $A$ ∈ $\Bbb C^{n×n}$ and let $A$ be a diagonal Matrix with entries $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ ∈ $\mathbb{C}$ Determine spec($A$*$A$)

I think it is clear that the spec ($A$ *$A$) = {$\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$}, as the  eigenvalues of a diagonal matix are just the elements on the diagonal. Could someone appove my thoughts?

Comment: have you tried verifying with particular examples?

Comment: well if we have a diagonal matrix 3x3 with 1,2,3 on the diagonal then the eigenvalues are just 1,2,3  so I suppose that for every diagonal matrix the eigenvalues are all the elements on the diagonal or am I wrong?

Comment: your above statement is correct, but have you computed the corresponding $A^*A$ and see what do you get?

Comment: I think that A*A  is the same as A trransponse times A  and that gives us also a diagonal matrix or???

Comment: yes, it's a diagonal matrix, refer to Fred's solution.

Answer (score 2):

$A^*A= diag(|\lambda_1|^2,....,|\lambda_n|^2)$

Thus the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ are ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact when you ll multiply twice the matrix, if you apply an eigenvector, you ll get the eigen value squared. It s quite obvious when you do the computation.
So you ll get

spec ($A$ *$A$) = {$\lambda_1^2 , \ldots, \lambda_n^2 $}

Moreover, I think this is true for any matrix, not only diagonals one.

Comment: Failing absolute values? The e-values of the conjugate matrix are conjugate to those of the initial matrix.

Comment: Conjugate? I was thinkikg that the star was the symbol of product of matrices

Comment: Written in the way of Fred there is no ambiguity but according to the question idk

Comment: it suffices to add a note in your solution explaining how you perceive A* A. 
   Usually, A* denotes the complex conjugate of A (especially, with a space in A* A)